# The best temmplate for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates

Can you tell me what's the best template for `CI` pls?
I'm using `CI 3.x`
I just want to show my `html` files in veiws 
Thank you

Comment: are u referring to markup or the structuring?

Comment: Can you explain how can i show my `html` files in `CI`??
I put a file in views/_layout/index.php and i want use that file(index.php)

Comment: see my answer. just use the folder name in load view statement . provide the path and your view will be loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to render a view (HTML) in codeigniter**

Step-1

You need to set a default controller . In your application folder go to config and open routes.php. Scroll down, find the line which says default_controller change it to

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Controller_Name";
```

Step-2

Place your HTML view file in Application -> views folder

[image]

Step-3

From your controller, create a function index and call that view

```
class Controller_Name extends CI_Controller 
{
 public function index() 
 {        
    $this->load->view('_layout/index');
 }
}
```

Step-4

Open your browser. Hoping that your server (xampp/wamp) is running. Type in URL 
http://localhost/projectFolder/index.php/Controller_Name

OR

http://localhost/projectFolder/

Where projectFolder is the name of the folder in which you have CI installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smarty Template Engine for HTML view.